# Bug in approving/rejecting an edit?

Tags: support, review

This relates to this [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/20026). I was reading this question and it showed edit(0). I clicked this and the popup page showed me the edit and I tried approving and I received the following message

"The Edit was already approved"

I closed and went to my Review Edit Page and I saw this question waiting for approval. I clicked "Approve" and received the following message

"This question needs one more approval....."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a bug (at least, if the chain of events went this way) - the user did gave two suggested answers. You linked to the [first](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/20025), while the history showed the [second (now approved) edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/20026).

This is probably because you can still edit your suggested answer before it is approved, so you approved his first edit while he submitted his improvement to his first edit, which ended up as a second edit. The first edit was approved at [15:13:57](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5353934/revisions). His second edit was submitted 3 seconds later, at [15:14:00](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/20026). The whole thing could be purely coincidental. (Although it is a little odd the 5 min editing grace period did not apply here)